# Ruby on Rails - How can I run automated tests on a user-uploaded Ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, file-upload, rspec

I'm currently working on a Rails application (React frontend) that deals with students submitting zipped directories of Ruby projects. The files are stored through Paperclip and S3 on an `Assessment` model. Currently, in order to grade student submissions, I must download every student file and test with RSpec individually from the command line.

I've improved the workflow through writing a command line script (in Ruby) that will take a directory of Zips, grade them all at once, and store each individual RSpec output in a scores.txt file.

The goal is to allow students to upload their .zips through a portal, and have them be immediately and automatically tested with RSpec. Is there a way to do this?

I've done a lot of searching, and so far can only find advice on how to test live user input (similar to codecademy, or other sites with integrated IDEs).

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is doable.

Unzip the file, load each file and run tests on the defined methods/classes.

But there are at least two things to consider...

### Security

A student could overwrite your `test` method to return only good grades, or random or whatever. Because you're basically loading their code into the same process that grades them. You can, of course, make the method names not obvious but [security through obscurity](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is just crossing your fingers and hope to be lucky (e.g. a student can make a script that uploads your source code somewhere to inspect later)

I'd solve it with a small API that takes the code, the source file, method to call and returns the output. So instead of loading the file in your space - you ask a separate app to produce output, and in your main app would evaluate/grate it.

### Consistency of results

i.e. one student could overwrite definition of `Object.to_s` and others would use it thinking it's the original implementation - thus making their code failing in producing the desired output.

Solution to this one would be to run each test in a separate process (not just thread)

This unfortunatelly brings us back to security - each script will be able to read and alter the code that's accessible by the app that runs it.

### So! What to do then?

The easiest thing I can think of right now is to start a container (i.e. docker, rocket or other) and run the code there. An additional benefit would be that you can share the container image with the students, and they can run their code in the same environment making the results as consistent as you can imagine.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, these sound really helpful!

A couple followups: 1 do you mean just calling ruby's `File` methods inside of the `Assessment` model? I could use backticks (i.e. `\`unzip filename.zip\``) to execute bash-like commands.

2. would it be possible if the files being tested are Rails files? (which includes a test database)

Comment: If the file _to be graded_ is a rails project, maybe I could set up a whole new Docker container just to setup that project?

Comment: I would imagine you expect students to define `foo` method (or whatever you wanna call it, but they have to implement it). And you say: `foo(x)` produces `false` when `x>0` and `true` otherwise. Then to test it, you require student's file, and call `foo` method and check the output. Ofc. you can use backticks, or `System.exec` to unzip it easily. If you need help with implementation you should start implementing, and search/ask specific questions on SO.